# Unable to get results from php to javascript using json

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am building a web chat app, but I am failing to retrieve messages from database and append them to the div. I am just trying out json for the first time so I think i messed up somewhere.

This is the script to call php and append results

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: "get_message.php",
   data: {msg_id:msg_id},
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(result){
       //all good.
       ///append to the chats.
       for(var i=0; i < result.length; i++){
           $("#chats").append("<p>" + result[i]['message'] + "</p>" +
                              "<p align=right>Sent by " + result[i]['sender'] + " at " + 
                               result[i]['time'] + "</p>");
       }
       $("#msg").val("");
       $('#chats').animate({scrollTop:$('#chats').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);
   }
 })
```

And this is the php file it is calling;

```
<?php
$msg_id = $_POST['msg_id'];
require("config.php");
$table = "messages";

$sql = "SELECT message, time, sender FROM $table WHERE chat_id = '$msg_id''";
$messages = array();

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $messages[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($messages);
} else {
    echo "No chats available";
}
?>
```

Comment: you will need to parse your json in your javascript side

Comment: console.log the result and post it here too. Then use jQuery to iterate over it

Comment: Worth checking the browser's debugger network tab to see what the response actually looks like

Comment: Check what the message array from php gives.

Comment: i have tried console.log(result) but it displays nothing in the console

Comment: By the way you also need to `json_encode` the string if you want the browser to handle it properly, either that or use `http_response_code(404)` and catch that via an AJAX error function.

Comment: you should add error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); and also, it seems like a typo occurred on this line $sql = "SELECT message, time, sender FROM $table WHERE chat_id = '$msg_id' ' "; (check the end of the line)

Comment: @apokryfos et me set up an ajax error function and see